# Python: create nested list from long format panda dataframes

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, where only "peak_time" is a column:

```
stimulus position peak_time 
1        1        1.0
         2        1.5
2        1        2.0
         2        2.0
3        1        2.5
```

Now I'm trying to squeeze the position column and get lists instead, so that it looks like this:

```
stimulus peak_time  
1        [1.0, 1.5]
2        [2.0, 2.0]
3        [2.5]
```

It's probably super easy, but I can't find any solution using goole. If someone opened this topic already, I'd appreciate the respective link, too. Thanks for your help!

**Code to create dataframe**:

```
import random, scipy
import pandas as pd
trial     = [1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2]
stimulus  = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3] 
position  = [1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1]
peak_time = random.sample(range(1000), 9)
df        = pd.DataFrame({"trial": trial, "stimulus": stimulus, "position": position, "peak_time": peak_time})
median_   = df.groupby(['stimulus', 'position']).apply(scipy.nanmedian)
median_   = pd.DataFrame(median_)
median_.columns = ['peak_time']
median_
```

***EDIT***

As I can only post one question every 90 minutes, I'd like to ask a follow up question underneath this post. So now I have two panda series looking like this:

```
median_:
stimulus
1    [1.0, 1.5]
2    [2.0, 2.0]
3    [2.0]

quartile_:
stimulus
1    [[1.0, 70.0],  [1.0, 183.25]]
2    [[1.0, 65.75], [2.0, 98.75]]
3    [[1.0, 51.25]]
```

I want to substract `median_` from `quartile_` so that I get

```
distance_: 
stimulus
1   [1-1, 70-1], [1.5-1, 183.25-1.5]
2   [2-1, 65.75-1], [2-2, 98.75-2]
3   [2-1, 51.25-2]
```

Is there a simple way to do that? `abs(median_ - quartile_)` does not work.

**Code to create series:**

```
import random, scipy
import pandas as pd
trial     = [1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2]
stimulus  = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3] 
position  = [1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1]
peak_time = random.sample(range(1000), 9)
df        = pd.DataFrame({"trial": trial, "stimulus": stimulus, "position": position, "peak_time": peak_time})
median_   = df.groupby(['stimulus', 'position']).apply(scipy.nanmedian).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
quartile_ = df.groupby(['stimulus', 'position']).apply(lambda x: scipy.nanpercentile(x, [25, 75])).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
```

***Solution***

Apply `groupby(level=0).apply(list)` later, so

```
median_   = df.groupby(['stimulus', 'position']).apply(scipy.nanmedian)
quartile_ = df.groupby(['stimulus', 'position']).apply(lambda x: scipy.nanpercentile(x, [25, 75]))
```

Then I can substract them easily

```
distance_ = abs(median_ - quartile_)
distance_ = distance.groupby(level=0).apply(list)
distance_

stimulus
1   [1-1, 70-1], [1.5-1, 183.25-1.5]
2   [2-1, 65.75-1], [2-2, 98.75-2]
3   [2-1, 51.25-2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `MultiIndex Series`, so need [`Series.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) `list`:

```
#added column peak_time
median_   = df.groupby(['stimulus', 'position'])['peak_time'].apply(scipy.nanmedian)
df        = median_.groupby(level=0).apply(list).reset_index()
print (df)
   stimulus   peak_time
0         1  [1.0, 1.5]
1         2  [2.0, 2.0]
2         3       [2.5]
```

Comment: That was probably the quickest response ever. Solves my problem entirely, thanks!! Gonna mark it as an answer in 6 min (stackoverflow makes me wait)..

Comment: I have a follow up question, maybe you know a quick solution for that, too?

Comment: @SvennoNito - Not so easy, because pandas native dont support nested list very nice.

Comment: @jezreal, I got a workaround, by applying your solution just on the distance measure. So `distance_ = median_ - quartile_` and then `distance_.groupby(level=0).apply(list) `